# In Swift UI, nothing appears to show on the screen when I use NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use Swift UI to create an app with buttons that open a new screen when they are pressed.  From looking on Google, it seems that NavigationView should be used for this.  I have a NavigationView with one button.  When I run the code using my iPad running IOS 13 beta, nothing seems to show on the screen.  I am blind and using VoiceOver, so it is possible that the button does show but VoiceOver does not see it.

I am using VStack because I plan to have a few of these buttons AKA NavigationLinks that open another screen.

```
import SwiftUI
struct WindowsShortCuts: View {
var body: some View {
    Text("This will show questions about Windows shortcuts.")
    }
}
```

struct ContentView: View {

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: WindowsShortCuts()) {
                Text("Windows shortcuts")
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Choose category"))
        }
    }
}
```

}

I expect there to be a button labeled "Windows shortcuts."  When I tap on the button, I expect it to open another screen.  Since I am testing, the screen should have some text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `NavigationLink(destination: WindowsShortCuts())`, You should use

```
NavigationButton(destination: WindowsShortCuts()) {
    Text("Windows shortcuts")
}.navigationBarTitle(Text("Choose category"))
```

I hope this will help you.

**Updated answer**

This is how it looks like -

```
struct ContentView : View {

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationButton(destination: WindowsShortCuts()) {
                Text("Window shortcut")
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Choose category"))
        }
    }
}}


struct WindowsShortCuts: View {
   var body: some View {
    Text("This will show questions about Windows shortcuts.")
}}
```

Comment: When I used NavigationButton, Xcode gave me an unresolved identifier error.

Comment: Have you just replaced the NavigationLink line only or putted my code at place of entire function? You should just change NavigationLink line with my code and let everything remain same as it was. 
I am also updating my answer to give you complete code snippet that is working on my xcode. Hope it will help you.

Comment: NavigationButton is no longer available, NavigationLink is its replacement.